# Open a new window from html email

Tags: html, asp.net, sendmail, html-email

I developed a web page in asp.net to send HTML email.
I did the coding for sending the mail in asp.net.
The issue is, after sending the mail I need to open a popup window from the mail using hyperlink.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a comment on another answer:

> I need to open it as a popup window. Not in a new tab.

That requires JavaScript. You cannot run JavaScript in an email. Therefore you cannot achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<a href='yourULR' target="_blank"> description </a>
```

This should make it open as a pop-up (unless default browser setting are different)

Although it's not recommended to use pop ups anymore because most users find it extremely annoying.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, just put your:

```
<a href='yourULR'>description</a>
```

in your email

Comment: really strange, its a common task in html emails, post your rendered html

Comment: In the html page which I used to send as an email only have an hyperlink like the one there in your answer.

Comment: I need to open it as a popup window. Not in a new tab.